# Get the object that a function was called from in python

Tags: python

If I have a class that contains a method, and I call that method from an instance, how do I get the specific instance it was called from?

e.g. I have a class:

```
class foo:
   def __init__(self):
      pass
   def do_something(self):
      bar()
```

I also have a function:

```
def bar():
   print()
```

If i make an object, e.g. `obj = foo()`, and then i call `obj.do_something()`, How would i get `obj` from inside my `bar()` function?

Comment: It's the first argument to the method, normally called `self`.

Comment: That won't help me though because `self` isn't passed into `bar` so I don't have access to it.

Comment: So, pass it to `bar`.  Otherwise `bar` won't be able to access it.

Comment: but the point is to not have to pass it to bar. I know you can do some things with the insepct module to find the function name and file it was called from, but I couldn't find anywhere how to get a reference to the object, so I was asking here in case anyone knew

Comment: You can get some information from the `traceback` package, or the `inspect` package, but it may not be enough for your needs.

Comment: Why would `bar` care about the value of `self`, if it doesn't necessarily have to be called from *any* method?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem; what problem are you trying to solve that `bar` needs such a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the inspect module, you can get the caller frame and access its local variables, in particular the `self` argument representing the instance:

```py
import inspect


def bar():
    caller = inspect.stack()[1].frame
    localvars = caller.f_locals
    self = localvars['self']
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this only *assumes* that the name `self` is bound to some object that invoked a method. `self` *could* be used for anything, and further, `bar` has no business assuming that it is being called from inside a method, or in any other specific context, for that matter.

Comment: @chepner I'm assuming this is not destined for production and is more of a hack, and that the question asker does not have control over the `foo` class code. You probably don't want to use `inspect` in a serious project anyway.

Comment: I am getting an error while executing your code: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'frame' .

Comment: @NandiniAshokTuptewar If you're using Python 2, you must replace `.frame` by `[0]`, as the frame infos returned by stack were tuples and not named tuples yet.